# What is the fastest way to do this in c++ (Using OpenMP)

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp

I have an algorithem that I can write in psedu code as follow:

```
for(int frame=0;frame <1000;frame++)
{
     Image *img=ReadFrame();
     mat processedImage=processImage(img);
     addtompeg(processedImage);
}
```

ProcessImage is time consuming and would takes around 30 sec. ReadFrame an AddToMpeg are not slow but they need to be done sequentially (otherwise, fame 2 may be added to output before frame 1).

How can I parallelize   it using OpenMP?

I am using opencv to readframe and addtompeg.

Comment: Maybe a GPU-based approach (OpenCL / CUDA) is the way to go here, to unload your CPU / speedup your application the most possible. But it requires a lot more effort than just doing it in some other thread. Just my thoughts on this ;) PS: OpenCV has an [OpenCL module](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/ocl.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, in OpenMP you may execute a portion of a `for` loop in the same order as if the program was sequential using the `ordered` clause (see section 2.8.7 [here](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf)). Anyhow I would not suggest using this clause for two reasons:

1. a thread **must not** execute more than one ordered region in the same loop (which seems not to be your case)
2. in many implementations an `ordered` loop behaves much like a sequential loop, with detrimental effects on performance

Therefore what I would suggest in your case is to unroll the loop:

```
Image * img           [chunk];
mat     processedImage[chunk];
/* ... */
for(int frame = 0; frame < nframes; frame += chunk) {

  #pragma omp single
  { /* Frames are read in sequential order */
    for( int ii = frame; ii < frame + chunk; ii++) {
       img[ii%chunk] = ReadFrame();
    }
  } /* Implicit barrier here */
  #pragma omp for
  for( int ii = frame; ii < frame + chunk; ii++) {
       processedImage[ii%chunk] = processImage(img[ii%chunk]); /* Images are processed in parallel */
  } /* Implicit barrier here */
  #pragma omp single
  { /* Frames are added to mpeg sequential order */
    for( int ii = frame; ii < frame + chunk; ii++) {
     addtompeg(processedImage[ii%chunk]);
    }
  } /* Implicit barrier here */
}
```

The value of `chunk` depends mainly on considerations about memory. If you think that memory will not be a problem, then you can completely remove the outer loop and let the inner one go from `0` to `nframes`.

Of course care must be taken to correctly manage the remainders of the outer loop (which I have not shown in the snippet).

Answer (score 1):

Building on the chunking idea of Massimiliano, a more elegant solution is to use the explicit tasking mechanism of OpenMP 3.0 and later (which means that it would not work with the C++ compiler from Visual Studio):

```
const int nchunks = 10;

#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp single
   {
      mat processedImage[nchunks];

      for (int frame = 0; frame < nframes; frame++)
      {
         Image *img = ReadFrame();

         #pragma omp task shared(processedImage)
         {
            processedImage[frame % nchunks] = processImage(img);
            disposeImage(img);
         }

         // nchunks frames read or the last frame reached
         if ((1 + frame) % nchunks == 0 || frame == nframes-1)
         {
            #pragma omp taskwait

            int chunks = 1 + frame % nchunks;
            for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++)
               addtompeg(processedImage[i]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The code might look awkward, but it is conceptually very simple. If it wasn't for the OpenMP constructs, it would be just like a serial code that buffers up to `nchunks` processed frames before it adds them in a loop to the output MPEG file. The magic happens in this block of code:

```
#pragma omp task shared(processedImage)
{
   processedImage[frame % nchunks] = processImage(img);
   disposeImage(img);
}
```

This creates a new OpenMP task that executes the two lines of code in the block. `img` and `frame` are captured by value, i.e. they are `firstprivate`, therefore it is not necessary for `img` to be an array of pointers. The producer task gives the ownership of `img` to the task and therefore the task has to take care of disposing the image object. It is important here that `ReadFrame()` allocates each frame in a separate buffer and does not reuse some internal memory each time (I've never used OpenCV and I don't know if this is the case or not). Tasks are queued and executed by idle threads waiting at some task scheduling point. The implicit barrier at the end of the `single` construct is such a scheduling point, therefore the remaining threads will start executing the tasks. Once that `nchunk` frames have been read or the end of the input has been reached, the producer thread waits for all queued tasks to be processed (that's what the `taskwait` is for) and then simply writes the chunks to the output.

Selecting the proper value of `nchunks` is important, otherwise some of threads might end up idling. If `ReadFrame` and `addtompeg` are relatively fast, i.e. reading and writing `num_threads` frames takes less time than `processImage`, then `nchunks` should be an exact multiple of the number of threads. If `processImage` can take varying amount of time, then you would need to set a really large value of `nchunks` in order to prevent load imbalance. In this case I would rather try to parallelise `processImage` instead and keep the processing loop serial.